# robocopy, jungledisk file copy problems

Tags: amazon-s3, robocopy, jungledisk

I'm a huge fan of robocopy and use it extensively to copy between various servers I need to update.

Lately I've been archiving to an Amazon S3 account that I access via a mapped drive using JungleDisk.  I then robocopy my files from local PC to S3.

Sometimes I get a very strange 'Incorrect function' error message in robocopy and the file fails to copy.  I've tried xcopy and straightforward copy and paste between file explorer windows.  In each case I get some variation of the 'Incorrect function' or 'Illegal MS-DOS function' and the file will never copy.

I delete the target but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you're allowed to answer your own questions but I think I've fixed it...

I found this in the [jungledisk support forums](http://forum.jungledisk.com/viewtopic.php?t=14039&highlight=invalid+msdos+function)

> The quick solution is to zip the
>   files, delete the original, then unzip
>   the files because zip can't handle
>   extended attributes. Another solution
>   is to move them to a FAT filesystem,
>   then move again to NTFS filesystem,
>   because FAT don't manage extended
>   attributes.
>
> In both cases the result is the
>   deletion of extended attributes, and
>   the files can be moved to the
>   jungledisk.
>
> The files can have extended attributes
>   for different reasons, expecially
>   migrations from other filesystems: in
>   my case was the migration of a CVS
>   repository from a ext2 filesystem to
>   NTFS.

Seems to have worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues from both OSX and linux.  At first I was not concerned by it but then it occurred to me these issues could result in potential data contamination or backup failure.  So I have abandon JungleDisk for everything except my lightweight work.

Zipping/taring files was not an option for me because of the size of my data set.  With this approach you have to upload your entire data set each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which attributes you refer to but could you robocopy with the /COPY:DT switch to strip off the attributes?